# Why do I get a syntax error on the elif statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty sure I have indented the code properly and left no parentheses open.

```
a,b = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
N = int(input())
C = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
for i in range(0,len(C)-1):
    if (a+C[i] == b) or (b + C[i] == a):
        print(C[i])
        break
    elif:
        for j in range(0,len(C)-1):
            if (a+C[i]) == (b+C[j]):
                print(C[j],C[i])
                break
    else:
        print("NOT POSSIBLE")
```

Comment: Your `elif` has no conditional. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Comment: You need to test for a condition in the elif statement. Elif(something):

Comment: When do you expect your `elif` to run?

Comment: To explain other comments: `elif` is a shortcut for `else if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to use an `elif` you need a condition just like on your `if`.  Example:

```
if a == b:
    do_something()
elif a == c:
    do_something_else()
```